# Why doesn't my input in my SharePoint WebPart changes value?

Tags: javascript, c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I am trying to change the value of an hidden input every n seconds with a timer in my webpart.ascx.cs to retrieve the value later on in JavaScript, but the value never seems to change. Can you help me figuring out why?

Here's an exemple of what I'm trying to do :

```
//Initialising the timer
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer timer = new Timer(10 * 1000);
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(changeValue);
    timer.Start();
}

private void changeValue(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    myInput.Value = "Changed Value";
}
```

Then in my ascx I have this input:

```
<input id="myInput" type="hidden" runat="server" />
```

If I call changeValue in Page_Load, the value of the input does change, but when it is called afterward with the timer, the value stays the same in the Javascript side.

```
//Work for the first time, but not when the timer elapsed.
var myInputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: if you needed to update the value of an input with server side logic, then you could use an `UpdatePanel`. This allows for server side postbacks to happen asynchronously, and therefore update the client side input value.

Comment: @tigerdi Thanks! I checked out the UpdatePanels and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked up the UpdatePanels as @tigerdi suggested me and I was able to update the html from the server side using an ASP Timer. Here the solution that I found :

This Is my UpdatePanel and my timer.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel id="updatePanel" runat="server" `UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Timer ID="timer" OnTick="timer_Tick" Interval="10000" runat="server"></asp:Timer>
    <input id="myInput" type="hidden" runat="server" />
</ContentTemplate>
```

Then with the event timer_Tick, I can change the value of my input and then call the UpdatePanel Update() function like so

```
protected void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myInput.Value = "Changed Value";
    updatePanel.Update();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your timer code, and the Timer object, are running in server side code. Once the page has loaded, the server side code cannot change the client side HTML. If you want the  tag to get updated every n seconds/milliseconds, then you should be using client site Javascript setTimeout(function, milliseconds) or setInterval(function, milliseconds).

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp